# Hibernate 5.2: java.transaction.xa package conflict in Java 9

Tags: java, hibernate, java-9

I'm trying to familiarise myself with Java 9's module system and have come across something I can't immediately see how to resolve.

I have a Maven project that has dependencies on both JDK9's `java.sql` and `hibernate-core` (5.2.11.Final). Hibernate transitively pulls in `jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec`. Both that jar and the `java.sql` module contain the package: `java.transaction.xa`, therefore the compiler throws a load of these errors at me:

```
Error:java: the unnamed module reads package javax.transaction.xa from both jboss.transaction.api.1.2.spec and java.sql
```

I thought I'd resolved this by doing this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate-entitymanager.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

However, though it compiles it later throws this exception at runtime:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.transaction.SystemException
```

It turns out that `javax.transaction.SystemException` is in the excluded `jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec` dependency, so I can't exclude it. But neither can I not depend on `java.sql` which contains `java.sql.DataSource` which I also use!

How do I resolve this problem of a module and .jar ('Automatic module'?) containing two equivalently named packages, but containing different classes? Both of which I need!

**EDIT**

I took a look at [Hibernate, Java 9 and SystemException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46515230/hibernate-java-9-and-systemexception) but that seems to shift the problem, so now the compiler just complains about the same package in `java.sql` and `javax.transaction.api`

```
Error:java: the unnamed module reads package javax.transaction.xa from both java.sql and javax.transaction.api
```

The crux of the problem is that the `java.transaction.xa` package exists in both modules.

It seems this is a known problem, I can't see if there's any clear/easy resolution to it:

https://developer.jboss.org/message/960718#960718