# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.transaction.SystemException entityManagerFactory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I got this error.Some solutions said add javax.transaction to pom.xml.I did but not working.And some solutions said javaee.jar and javax.persistence.jar to my classpath.But not working.So how to i fix it?

User model

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class Users implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="surname")
    private String surname;

    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="is_super_user")
    private Boolean isSuperUser;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;


    @Column(name="created_at")
    private Date created_at;

    @Column(name="updated_at")
    private Date updated_at;


    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        created_at = new Date();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    protected void onUpdate() {
        updated_at = new Date();
    }//and getter&setter
```

UserDao

```
@Repository
public class UsersDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void save(Users users){
        entityManager.persist(users);
    }
}
```

UserDto like model without this constructor

```
public UsersDto(){

}

public UsersDto(Users users){
    this.id = users.getId();
    this.name = users.getName();
    this.surname = users.getSurname();
    this.email = users.getEmail();
    this.isSuperUser = users.getSuperUser();
    this.username = users.getUsername();
    this.password = users.getPassword();
}
```

UserResources

```
    @Component
@Path("/users")
public class UsersResources {
    @Autowired
    UsersService usersService;

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response saveCity(UsersDto usersDto){
        Users users;

        try{
            users = usersService.saveUsers(usersDto);

        }catch (Exception e){
            return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
        return Response.ok(users).build();
    }
}
```

UserServices

```
    @Service
public class UsersService {

    @Autowired
    private UsersDao usersDao;

    @Transactional
    public Users saveUsers(UsersDto usersDto){

        Users users = new Users();
        users.setName(usersDto.getName());
        users.setEmail(usersDto.getEmail());
        users.setSuperUser(usersDto.getSuperUser());
        users.setSurname(usersDto.getSurname());
        users.setPassword(usersDto.getPassword());
        usersDao.save(users);

        return users;
    }

}
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException
    at 
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375) ~[na:na]
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger$1.run(Logger.java:2554) ~[jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar:3.3.2.Final]
```

My pom.xml has spring boot starter (web security jersey jpa mysql) and javax.transaction

So how to i fix?

Comment: Try to understand where the class is supposed to be coming from. If you want to know for sure if a `.class` existing in a `.jar` file then you can unzip the `.jar` and make sure it's actually there. `unzip some-lib.jar`. Once you find what `.jar` the `.class` is in then you need to make sure it's included in the classpath. ie the argument to `java -cp <classpath> ...`

Comment: Maybe this help: [hibernate-java-9-and-systemexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46515230/hibernate-java-9-and-systemexception) They also wrote something about `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException` in a Spring Boot environment.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried all solutions but did not working.If you want to try https://github.com/SmartAdvertisement/WebApi .I think maybe because of dependency failure

Answer (score 0):

You made `javax:javaee-web-api:6.0` be a `provided`-scope dependency in your `pom.xml` file. This is stating that you expect it to be provided by your container at runtime. The `NoClassDefFoundException` would seem to indicate it is not being provided at runtime (maybe you're using Tomcat instead of TomEE?).

Try removing the `<scope>` element from the `javaee-web-api` dependency in `pom.xml` - you may well just get different errors at runtime (if you don't have an implementation available, for example), but this will get you past this specific error.

Comment: I got this error when `mvn install` .I have not use TomEE yet.I created project by spring initlzr.This mean I do not think there is any dependency dispute.So i removed `<scope>`  element from the `javaee-web-api` . Unfortunately the error has not changed.