# java ORM Hibernate Exception in java 10

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm fairly new to Hibernate ORM. Trying to Compile small Program in java with Hibernate.This is simple program that trying to insert one record to MySQL database.Below  I listed all the code i have in Student and Process class .I'm Getting various errors every time i trying to execute My Project.

After do some research i Added all libraries listed below too.

**

### javax.activation-1.2.0.jar

### jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar

### jaxb-core-2.3.0.jar

### jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar**

then later added

### jta-1_1.jar

### jboss.jar

### javaee.jar

now i'm getting different error listed as

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger$1.run(Logger.java:2554)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2529)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2516)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CoreLogging.messageLogger(CoreLogging.java:28)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CoreLogging.messageLogger(CoreLogging.java:24)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:85)
    at ADP.Process.main(Process.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.transaction.SystemException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 10 more
```

this is my Student Class

```
package ADProcess;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student
{
@Id
@Column(name="StudentName")
private String StudentName ;

@Column(name="City")
private String City ;

@Column(name="Country")
private String Country;


@Column(name="Age")
private int Age;


public Student()
{

}

public Student(String studentName, String city, String country, int age) 
{

    StudentName = studentName;
    City = city;
    Country = country;
    Age = age;
} 


@Override
public String toString() 
{
    return "Student [StudentName=" + StudentName + ", City=" + City + ", Country=" + Country + ", Age=" + Age + "]";
}

/**
 * @return the studentName
 */
public String getStudentName() 
{
    return StudentName;
}

/**
 * @param studentName the studentName to set
 */
public void setStudentName(String studentName) 
{
    StudentName = studentName;
}
/**
 * @return the city
 */
public String getCity() 
{
    return City;
}
/**
 * @param city the city to set
 */
public void setCity(String city) 
{
    City = city;
}
/**
 * @return the country
 */
public String getCountry() 
{
    return Country;
}
/**
 * @param country the country to set
 */
public void setCountry(String country) 
{
    Country = country;
}
/**
 * @return the age
 */
public int getAge() 
{
    return Age;
}
/**
 * @param age the age to set
 */
public void setAge(int age) 
{
    Age = age;
}






}
```

and this my my Main Class called Process

```
 package ADProcess;


import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class Process {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{


    SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass(Student.class).buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

    try
    {
        Student student = new Student("Aruna","Newport News","Sri Lanka",29);
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(student);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    finally
    {

        factory.close();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49585906/hibernate-java-9-javax-transaction-systemexception

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44385846/hibernate-5-issue-with-jdk-9

Comment: The problem is you've configured it to use JTA, when you're not using JTA. You need to specify a non-jta-datasource.

Comment: Can you please explain it furthermore ..! how I'm going to  do that ..?